# Android Enable/Disable Usage of 3G for my application

Tags: android, networking

I'm curious is there any way in Android, so I can set my application to use 3G network or not to do it. If 3G is not allowed I need my application to use only Wifi even if there is no available Wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WifiManager::getConnectionInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConnectionInfo%28%29) to get info if wifi is connected or not before you make any network calls.